# Stop a Function/ EventListener once another has been called

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to write a drawing app using html5 canvas.

I have set an image as background.  A stroked rectangle animated with clearRect is used to select a square from the background image.  On mousedown the canvas is transformed and scaled and the selected square of image is drawn on to the canvas.

Once a square is selected I want to stop the clearRect function so that I can start the drawing function.  Unfortunately, and despite checking historical posts, I can't get the scaled image to stay and it is immediately cleared because the select function is still active.

Here's my javascript code:

```
function doFirst(){
var x = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas=x.getContext('2d');
canvas.strokeStyle = "red";
canvas.fillStyle="black";
canvas.font = "bold 36px Arial";
}

function select(e){
xPos=Math.floor(e.clientX/100)*100;
yPos=Math.floor(e.clientY/100)*100;
canvas.clearRect(0,0,500,800);
canvas.strokeRect(xPos+1,yPos+1,99,99);
}

function zoom(e) {
var xPos=e.clientX;
var yPos=e.clientY;
canvas.scale(5,5);
canvas.translate(-Math.floor(xPos/100)*100,-Math.floor(yPos/100)*100);
canvas.strokeStyle="transparent";
var pic= new Image();
pic.src = "tut.jpg";
pic.addEventListener ("load",function(){canvas.drawImage(pic,0,0)},false);
}

window.addEventListener ("load", doFirst, false);
window.addEventListener ("mousemove", select, false);
window.addEventListener ("mousedown", zoom, false);
```

Thanks very much,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
window.removeEventListener ("mousemove", select, false);
```

Comment: Brilliant!  remove.. add... ahhh!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite following what you mean, but the mousemove listener is fired many times a second while the mouse moves?

Comment: I want the mousemove listener to stop once I have zoomed in - coco has a very elegant solution for me.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(e){e.stopPropagation();doFirst}, true);
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){e.stopPropagation();select}, true);
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){e.stopPropagation();zoom}, true);
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution.  Enables me to stop the zoom and select functions from within the zoom function - removeEventListener worked for the select function but not the zoom function for some reason.